# Serving images from a protected folder to a phonegap app

Tags: php, cordova, protected

I am currently working on an application using phonegap that requires images from my server to be displayed on the application when a button is clicked. I am trying to do this by having the button click send an HTTP POST request to a PHP script on my server. The POST request contains the name of the file on the server that needs to be displayed. However, I only want the images to be served to the phonegap client when the POST data is received: in other words, I don't want the folder with my images inside of it to be accessible from say a web browser.  How can I safely secure the folder containing my images, while also having them displayed to the application by a specific PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script, you can read and 'echo' the contents of images with the appropriate Content Types.

And place your images outside your /www directory or wherever you host your site, or you can edit .htaccess to disallow any access to the directory where all the images are placed.

Comment: So the way I have it set now I am echoing the image as an image source, (echo '<img src="'. $imgPath . '"/>';) Is there a different way to echo the contents of the image?